# How do i remove the x axis 0 line on a plotly chart with streamlit?

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I have a plotly chart visualized with streamlit, but when I load it on the hosted streamlit service `{appname}.streamlit.app`, it applies a black horizontal like at 0 that doesn't show up on local host.

Any idea on how to fix this?

`showline = False` doesn't seem to work in the `xaxis` or `yaxis` update layout method either

[EXPECTED] Local Host Chart (No horizontal black line at 0)
[image]

Incorrected chart displaying on the streamlit hosted service
[image]

Edit (adding code):

```
price_data = btc_price()

drawdown_fig = px.line(price_data, x=price_data.Date, y=price_data.Price, title=f'Significant Bitcoin Drawdowns')

drawdown_fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(
        family="Proxima Nova",
        size=12,
        color="Black"
    ),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    showlegend = False,
    xaxis=dict(
        title=None,
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,
    ), 
    yaxis=dict(
        title=None,
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,

    ),
)


drawdown_fig.update_traces(line_color='#27B296', line_width=1)

drawdown_fig.add_annotation(x=dt.date(2011, 6, 1), 
            y=5500,
            text="Jun 2011<br>-99%",
            showarrow=False,
            )

#removed the other annotations here for simplicity / to save space

st.plotly_chart(drawdown_fig)
```

Comment: Something like this `fig.update_xaxes(showline=False, layout=dict(showline=False))` and
`fig.update_yaxes(showline=False, layout=dict(showline=False))` don't work?

Comment: Hard to say anything without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at least some piece of code.

Comment: can you include the code you used to generate this plot? otherwise it will be difficult for us to reproduce the error in behavior that you're getting

Comment: added code snipped above, thanks all for the help

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify your `yaxis` configuration to add `zeroline=False`. I am pretty sure that would remove the horizontal black line at 0 on the hosted streamlit service.

```
yaxis=dict(
    title=None,
    showgrid=False,
    showline=False,
    zeroline=False,
)
```